# Vue CLI 3.0 project not working on IE11, SCRIPT1003: Expected ':' error with blank screen

Tags: vue.js, internet-explorer-11, vue-cli

this is in my package.json file

"browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]

also i have tried to install babel-polyfill but no luck.

Please note that i want to use method shorthand and other es6 syntax.

Comment: Copy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52056358/vue-cli-3-project-not-working-on-ie-11

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VUE CLI-3 Project not working on IE-11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52056358/vue-cli-3-project-not-working-on-ie-11)

Comment: @javimoi Lars Beck i have tried the same but still face the same issue!!!

Comment: Did you try to explicitly target IE11 with `"IE 11"`?

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution for this. putting here if someone face the same issue.
Issue was, i have installed  "vue-offline": "^1.0.204" plugin, and that was creating issue in ie. this is not supporting in vue cli 3.0. you need to upgrade this plugin with the latest one to fix this.

with vue cli 3.0 it is not required to install any polyfil externally to support legacy browsers, vue cli is taking care of all this.

Thanks for your support.