# Unhandled promise rejection InvalidCharacterError in IE11 with VEE Validate Vue.js and babel-polyfill

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internet-explorer-11, vee-validate, babel-polyfill

I have a problem in IE11 where i get a InvalidCharacterError when i validate a form with vee validate in vue.js. I think it could be a polyfill error but i'm not quite sure. I tried removing certain parts of my code to see if the problem is still there but i found nothing so far. I also tried labeling errors to see where the error is. I tried other solutions but nothing worked so far.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyYIn.png

Here is some code:

```
validateBeforeSubmit() {
    this.$validator.validateAll().then(result => {
        if (result) {
            //submit
        }
    })
}
```

the error only occurs when i press the submit button

edit:

this problem occured again recently. I already had babel-polyfill and i had imported it. I have other pages that use arrow functions and promises and those work fine in IE11.

Comment: IE doesn't know/understand [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility) and [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions is [not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility) by IE 11. You need to polyfill all the ES6+ syntax to make it compatible with IE 11. You could use [babel](https://babeljs.io/repl) to polyfill the code in your question:

```
(void 0).$validator.validateAll().then(function (result) {  
  if (result) {
      //submit
    }
});
```

You could also refer to the accepted answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52056358/vue-cli-3-project-not-working-on-ie-11/52115290#52115290) about installing and importing `babel-polyfill` to make vue.js app compatible with IE 11.