# Vue Router is not working my Project in IE

Tags: vue.js, internet-explorer, frontend

vue-cli-3 is not work in ie9,
error message is "Unable to get '_route' property that is undefined or null reference"

I'm setted vue-cli 'modern build'. 
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html#modern-mode

my babel config.

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: ["@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset", "@babel/preset-env"]
};
```

[image]

Comment: Is the project working in IE 11? Could you please provide [a minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the issue? So that we can have a test and see where the problem is. Besides, you could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52056358/vue-cli-3-project-not-working-on-ie-11/52115290#52115290) about polyfilling vuejs project to make it run in IE.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to update the `.browserslist` to include IE9.

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html#browserslist

See here specify browser ranges to target IE 9.
https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist

Comment: thanks, but it was not wroking in ie9...same error  ;{