# Blank pages on IE on html project using vue js cdn

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cdn, babel-polyfill

I created a project in html using the cdn for vue js. It works perfectly for chrome, but when I try to test it on IE11 it shows only blank pages.

I know that when using the vue-cli with webpack there is a workaround this issue using polyfill.

Is there any way to make it work on IE using cdn?

IE err: SCRIPT1003: Expected ':'

My vue js code:

```
<script>
  new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: function() {
   return {
     showAutomate: false,
     passwordField: null,
     login: false,
   }
 },
 methods: {
  checkPassword() {
    if (this.passwordField === "test") {
      this.login = true;
    }
    else {
      window.confirm(
        "Wrong password! Try again."
      );
    }
  },
 },
 created() {
   this.$vuetify.theme.themes.light.primary = "#0c343d";     
 },
 mounted() {

 }
})
</script>
```

Comment: is there any error in console of the IE?

Comment: I'm getting a SCRIPT1003: Expected ':' error. I checked the line where the error shows but there seems to not be any issue

Comment: well ... show the code around that line (add it to the question, don't put it in a comment), I bet you're using ES6 syntax that IE will never support

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52056358/vue-cli-3-project-not-working-on-ie-11