# Vue App Blank page in IE-11 and Ms Edge 40

Tags: vue.js, internet-explorer, vue-component, internet-explorer-11

I was given a Vue app that is working perfectly in Chrome, Firefox.
But blank page in IE-11 and Ms Edge. No Erorrs in console.
I'm not a Vue developer but I'm interested in Vue. So Tried to find a solution googling it. But no of those solutions works for me. Can someone please tell me what should I do to fix this blank page issue in IE-11 & Edge?.

**main.js**

```
import 'babel-polyfill'
import Vue from 'vue'

import Request from './http/request'

const EXCLUDED_PROD = [
    '52.59.217.237',
    'localhost'
]
```

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        ['@vue/app', {
            polyfills: [
                'es6.promise',
                'es6.symbol'
            ]
        }]
    ]
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>fav.png">
    <title>Starline Security</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but Starline Security doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
     <!--built files will be auto injected-->
  </body>
</html>
```

**package.json**

```
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
```

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52056358/vue-cli-3-project-not-working-on-ie-11

Comment: And : https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html#usebuiltins-usage

Comment: Thanks @Ehsansepehri. I tried this slution but still Blank page.

Comment: It's work perfectly, May i see your code?

Comment: You mean the whole code?

Comment: Please provide a minimal code sample which can reproduce the issue. You could refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) about how to provide a code sample. With only the above description, we can't locate the issue.

Comment: Main.js or index.js + babel.config.js

Comment: @Ehsansepehri I updated the question with the code.

Answer (score 1):

How do you create your vue project? I create vue project according to [this link](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#vue-create) and choose default. It can run well in IE and Edge without installing other packages.

I compared the files in the working project with yours and the **babel.config.js** and **package.json** are different. You could try to edit your **babel.config.js** and **package.json** according to below.

**babel.config.js:**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ]
}
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "hello-world",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.4.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Besides, it seems that your **main.js** is not complete. Mine is like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```